# How can I tag Azure resources retroactively?

Tags: azure, cost-management

I have an azure resource that is running for few days and only Later was tagged. The issue is that the days that the resource was running but did still was not tagged are being shown as "untagged" on Cost Analysis view. On that light I have two questions:

1. **Is there any way so I can tag a resource retroactively by providing a "Start-Date" in which the resource should be tagged?**
2. **If a resource is already deleted, is there any chance that I tag it for cost analisys purposes?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add tags for CreatedDate by enforcing the policy, Is this the thing, which you are looking for ?

Comment: hi @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT, not sure what you mean.

For example: I created a resource two days ago ago and today I decided that I want to track resources with a specific tag. Is there any possibiltiy that I set this tag for the same date when I create the resource?

Othwerise I would see on reporting:

 - Day 1: Untagged 10€
 - Day 2: Untagged 10€
 - Day 3: MyNew tag 10€
 - Day 4: MyNew tag 10€

How do I set the MyNew Tag for Day 1 and Day 2?